# PHP send email foreach - send to

Tags: php, email

I'm using a script to send email to checked users (approval), but script is sending only to first checked user, here's the script:

```
if (isset($_POST['approve'])) {
    $ticked = $_POST['approve'];

    foreach($ticked as $id) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id='".intval($id)."'";
        $result = mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $fname = $db_field['first_name'];
            $lname = $db_field['last_name'];
            $email = $db_field['email'];
            $fon = $db_field['telephone'];
            $ad = $db_field['ad'];

            $data = json_decode($ad);

            $message = 'Approved message';

            mail($mail, 'Your Subject', $message);

            set_include_path(getcwd()."/../library/");

            include_once("Google_Spreadsheet.php");

            $u = "hjgfhjgfh@gmail.com";
            $p = "sdgfdjkgfjg";

            $ss = new Google_Spreadsheet($u, $p, "Registracija_nova", "Sheet1");
            $row = array(
                "id" = > "=ROW() - 2",
                "name" = > $fname,
                "last_name" = > $lname,
                "email" = > $email,
                "phone_number" = > $fon,
                "address" = > $data - > address,
                "prevozbg" = > $data - > prevozbg,
                "skipass" = > $data - > skipass
            //"json" => $ad
            );

            $ss - > addRow($row);

            mysql_query("DELETE FROM userinfo WHERE `id` = '".intval($id)."'");

            /*
            $ImePrezimePos = "HP EG NPI - Registracija";
            $EmailAdresaPos = "hp_eg_npi@eventregistration.rs";
            $pfw_header = "From: ". $ImePrezimePos . " <" . $EmailAdresaPos . ">\r\n";
            $pfw_header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $pfw_header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            $pfw_subject = "Potvrdni email";
            $pfw_email_to = "$email";
            $msg = "Poštovani/a $fname $lname Vaša registracija je odobrena od strane administratora.<br/> Vaš HP tim";
            */

            //$msg = "Dear $fname $lname your registration was confirmed by admin.";
            //mail($email, 'Confirmation', $msg);
            //mail($pfw_email_to, $pfw_subject ,$msg ,$pfw_header ) ;

            $pfw_header. = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $pfw_header. = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

            $fromName = "HP EG NPI - Registracija";
            $fromEmail = "hp_eg_npi@eventregistration.rs";
            $toEmail = "$email";
            $subject = "Prijava prihvacena";

            function sendEmail($fromName, $fromEmail, $toEmail, $subject, $emailBody, $pfw_header) {
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail - > FromName = $fromName;
                $mail - > From = $fromEmail;
                $mail - > AddAddress("$toEmail");

                $mail - > Subject = $subject;
                $mail - > Body = $emailBody;
                $mail - > isHTML(true);
                $mail - > WordWrap = 150;

                if (!$mail - > Send()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function readTemplateFile($FileName) {
                $fp = fopen($FileName, "r") or exit("Unable to open File ".$FileName);
                $str = "";
                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $str. = fread($fp, 1024);
                }
                return $str;
            }

            //Data to be sent (Ideally fetched from Database)
            $name = "$first_name";
            $lastname = "$last_name";
            $UserEmail = "$email";


            //Send email to user containing username and password
            //Read Template File 
            $emailBody = readTemplateFile("../html-email/mail2.html");

            //Replace all the variables in template file
            $emailBody = str_replace("#username#", $fnames, $emailBody);
            $emailBody = str_replace("#password#", $lnames, $emailBody);

            //Send email
            $emailStatus = sendEmail($fromName, $fromEmail, $UserEmail, $subject, $emailBody, $headers);
        }
    }
}
```

And error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sendEmail() (previously declared in /home/^^/public_html/^^/admin/approve.php:82) in /home/^^/public_html/^^/admin/approve.php on line 82

And from previous file that's calling function:

```
echo "<input name=\"approve[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value='".$row["id"]."' >";
```

What can i do to make it send to each email i have checked? THanks in advance everybody!

Comment: what's in `$_POST['approve']`?

Comment: @MLeFevre echo "<input name=\"approve[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value='".$row["id"]."' >";

Comment: Your question has been answered. But you could have seen this yourself with good indentation.

Comment: Indentation is important. If you had that, you could have seen that your function was declared inside a loop and therefor creating that error.

Comment: @putvande I have fixed that, but now the email is being sent to only first user checked, but no error at least.

Comment: Add all your names and emails you want to mail in an array and add them all with `$mail->AddAddres(...,...);` Do that in the for loop ;)

Comment: Split your problem and ask a specific question about every specific problem you find. Do you know how to make a dynamic table with checkboxes? Do you know how to post the list of checked boxes and get that list in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `sendEmail()` function outside the `foreach` loop. Since it is inside the loop so you got the error **Cannot redeclare sendEmail()**

Comment: I have fixed that, but now the email is being sent to only first user checked, but no error at least.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `sendEmail()` function inside your loop. The function is defined in the first iteration of your loop, in the second iteration the error is thrown (because the function already exists) and your script stops. Move the function definition it out of the loop.

You should move ALL your function definitions out of the loop, a function can only be defined once.